# How to provide all functions associated with a struct in Racket

Tags: struct, module, racket

Is there a way to provide all of the functions associated with a `struct` without explicitly enumerating them?

For example, if I have `foo.rkt`:

```
#lang racket
(provide foo-struct) ; provide all functions, not just the constructor
(struct foo-struct (biz bop))
```

And then `bar.rkt`:

```
#lang racket
(require "foo.rkt")
(define foo (foo-struct 1 2)) ; works just fine
(foo-struct-biz foo) ; is undefined
```

Is there a way to provide `foo-struct-biz` and `foo-struct-bop` (and any other methods associated with the struct) without explicitly listing them?

Comment: https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/require.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._struct-out%29%29

Comment: Thanks @PetSerAl, not sure how I missed that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @PetSerAl in the comments, the way to do this is

```
(provide (struct-out foo-struct))
```

which will provide all of the methods associated with `foo-struct`.