# Racket: syntax for module to export the public functions of a class

Tags: racket

How can I use `provide` so that the `module` export all the public functions from a `class`?

On this website, I found out how to export all the get/set functions from a struct [1]. I didn't find any syntax for classes.

```
#lang racket
(provide (struct-out foo-struct))
(struct foo-struct (biz bop))
```

[1] [How to provide all functions associated with a struct in Racket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54890240/how-to-provide-all-functions-associated-with-a-struct-in-racket)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TLDR: you simply need to provide the class value.

The `struct` form defines accessors, setters, predicate, constructor, etc. Therefore, you need to provide them all if you want your client to have a full capability to manipulate structs:

```
(struct foo (bar) #:mutable)
;; this defines
;; constructor: foo
;; accessors: foo-bar
;; setters: set-foo-bar!
;; predicate: foo?
```

The `class` form, on the other hand, returns a first-class class value, and does not define anything at all. The class value then can be utilized by using forms such as `new` and `send` (which is provided by `#lang racket` already).

```
(class object% (super-new))
;; this defines nothing, but results in a class value
```

So it suffices to just provide an identifier bound to this class value. Here's an example:

```
;; lib.rkt

#lang racket

(define human% 
  (class object% (super-new)
    (define/public (speak)
      (displayln "hello world!"))))

(provide human%)
```

```
;; client.rkt

#lang racket

(require "lib.rkt")
(send (new human%) speak)
;; display hello world!
```

Answer (score 3):

`book.rkt`:

```
#lang racket

(provide book-class%)

(define book-class%
  (class object%
    (field (pages 5))
    (define/public (letters)
      (* pages 500))
    (super-new)))
```

In another file:

```
#lang racket

(require "book.rkt")

(define class-o (new book-class%))

(send class-o letters)
; => 2500
```

define/public was used to make the method in the class public, when the class is exported, that function can be used with `send`.